# `stat` output format: truncate a date field

Tags: bash, coreutils

In a `stat` format (at least the one I get from bash on Linux) one can use format modifiers: for instance `%010s` will force a size field to be at least 10 characters, padded to the left with zeroes (btw is this documented somewhere?)

Is there an equivalent trick to restrict the length of a field? I want to drop the decimal part of the second in the %xyz formats. Or will I have to postprocess the output with sed/awk?

Comment: A combination of `-c %Z` and using `date` to convert the seconds into whatever you want might be an option (macOS `stat` and `date` differ from the Linux version so I can't post an example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, since I can specify a printf-like length/pad (`%010s`, for instance), let's go back to the raw printf documentation, that documents a precision which is actually the maximum length of the field. And tadaaa.... it works in `stat` formats! (here truncated to keep just the date part):

```
stat -c '%.10y %10s %n' /boot/*
2018-05-17    1501659 /boot/abi-4.13.0-43-generic
2018-05-30    1501528 /boot/abi-4.13.0-45-generic
2018-05-17     213220 /boot/config-4.13.0-43-generic
2018-05-30     213220 /boot/config-4.13.0-45-generic
1970-01-01       4096 /boot/efi
2018-06-15       1024 /boot/grub
2018-05-22   52211016 /boot/initrd.img-4.13.0-43-generic
2018-06-22   52210415 /boot/initrd.img-4.13.0-45-generic
2017-04-08      12288 /boot/lost+found
2016-01-28     182704 /boot/memtest86+.bin
2016-01-28     184380 /boot/memtest86+.elf
2016-01-28     184840 /boot/memtest86+_multiboot.bin
2018-05-17        255 /boot/retpoline-4.13.0-43-generic
2018-05-30        255 /boot/retpoline-4.13.0-45-generic
2018-05-17    3884045 /boot/System.map-4.13.0-43-generic
2018-05-30    3883942 /boot/System.map-4.13.0-45-generic
2018-05-17    7713296 /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-43-generic
2018-05-22    7715224 /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-43-generic.efi.signed
2018-05-30    7712560 /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-45-generic
2018-06-14    7714488 /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-45-generic.efi.signed
```

Answer (score 20):

Using GNU tools,

```
date -r file +'%F %T %z'
```

This would get the timestamp of last modification of the given file (no subsecond resolution), and use `date` to reformat this into the same format as `stat -c %y file` would produce.

Example:

```
$ stat -c '%y' file
2021-03-17 08:53:39.540802643 +0100
```

```
$ date -r file +'%F %T %z'
2021-03-17 08:53:39 +0100
```

One can use `printf`-like formatting for the `%y` format specification directly, but not to modify a piece of the string in the middle:

```
$ stat -c '%.19y' file
2021-03-17 08:53:39
```

This truncates the string after 19 characters, which removes the subsecond data, but the time zone info is also left out.

Comment: The problem is that I need other pieces of information... the `stat` format isn't just the date.

Comment: @xenoid You asked specifically about truncating the timestamp. You never said what end result you wanted beyond that.

Answer (score 0):

here is a handy way to pluck out portions from stat timestamp then generate a custom date output

```
#!/bin/bash

given_file=$1   #  supply file to get backed up with timestamp

answer_interstital=$(stat -c '%.16y'  $given_file)  #   2021-08-23 15:09   stat given file extract out last changed timestamp using the -c flag
                                                    #   the   '%.16y'  specifies we want 16 character wide format of timestamp

first_portion=$( echo $answer_interstital  | cut -c6-7,9-10)     #  0823
second_portion=$(echo $answer_interstital  | cut -c12-13,15-16)  #  1509

cool_lastchanged_timestamp="${first_portion}_${second_portion}"  #  print both of above portions separated with an underbar

backup_filename=${given_file}~~${cool_lastchanged_timestamp}   #  create backup file using formatted timestamp

cp -p $given_file  $backup_filename # backup file from    some_file   to    some_file~~0823_1509
```

Comment: Why all the `echo`?

Answer (score 0):

Expanding a comment to the original question, given by @nohillside, the most flexible way to modify the format of a date information from the `stat` is employing the time since epoch that comes from it and to format it with the `date` command.

For example:

```
date --date="@"`stat -c '%Y' file` "+%F %r"
```

with a result:

```
2023-02-17 01:17:24 PM
```

in the `"+FORMAT"` argument you could use any modifier available for the date command, that you can check with `man date`.

Comment: Since the user is using `bash`, you can make this much more efficient (and portable to any GNU coreutils system with bash 4.2+) by using `printf`: `printf '%(%F %r)T\n' "$(stat -c %Y file)"` (use with `stat -f %m file` on BSD systems)