# `stat` output format: truncate a time field

Tags: bash, shell-script

Ref:[`stat` output format: truncate a date field](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/451554/stat-output-format-truncate-a-date-field)

The way they have extracted date from stat command by using:

```
stat -c '%.10y' file
```

My final command looks something like this:

```
stat -c "%y %i %A %n" *
```

I want to modify '%y' such that I only get the time. Instead of '.11' I want to define a range from 12 to 20.
Is there a way to do it, and what is this type of formatting called ?

by default the time is:

```
2021-06-19 13:46:30.201999800 +0530
```

but I want:

```
13:46:30
```

Final output:

```
13:46:29 11540474045615128 -rw-r--r-- __temp__
13:49:03 14918173767136212 -rw-r--r-- __TEM__.txt
13:46:29 9007199255101576 -rw-r--r-- bla.txt
13:49:58 1125899908323122 -rwxr-xr-x f.sh
13:46:30 1125899908323121 -rwxr-xr-x Q1 2.sh
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can format the string to show the date and time only and then use cut to get rid of the first column:

```
stat -c '%.19y %i %A %n' * | cut -d' ' -f2-
```

Edit:
Adding cut parameters description upon request.

```
-d' '   ; use space character as field delimiter
-f2-    ; print field number 2 and continue to end of line 
          (aka delete first field/column in this case)
```

Comment: Hi @ethcz, can you explain a little how is this working? How is cut command working and what is '--f2--'

Comment: @VanshikhaDhar use `man cut` to read the documentation where you can find out what the `-f` flag does. You can also experiment - start by comparing the output after using `cut` to the value generated by `stat` without `cut`

Comment: Note that it assumes that file names don't contain newline characters and don't start with `-`.

Answer (score 2):

You could always use `zsh`'s `stat` builtin instead (which predates GNU `stat`; beware different systems have different and incompatible implementations of `stat`, it's not a standard command):

```
#! /bin/zsh -
zmodload zsh/stat
for f (*(N)) {
  stat -F%T -LH s -- $f &&
    print -r $s[mtime] $s[inode] $s[mode] $f
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used awk to get the desired out

```
 stat -c '%y %i %A %n' k |awk '{gsub(/^[0-9]*-[0-9]*-[0-9]* /,"",$0);$2="";gsub(/\..*/,"",$1);print }'
```

Tested and worked fine